# convert dredge function outputs to data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am using the MuMIn package in R to select the best model for my data. Here, I use an example using the Cement data set provided with the code.

```
require(MuMIn)
data(Cement)
d <- data.frame(Cement)
idx <- seq(11,13)
avgmod.95p <- list()
for (i in 1:length(idx)){
  d2 <- d[1:idx[i],]
  fm1 <- lm(y ~ ., data = d2)
  dd <- dredge(fm1, extra = c("R^2", F = function(x)
    summary(x)$fstatistic[[1]]))

  # 95% confidence set:
  confset.95p <- get.models(dd, cumsum(weight) <= .95)
  avgmod.95p[[i]] <- model.avg(confset.95p)
}
```

As you can see, I'm running and iteration loop to construct the model average estimate for the dataset (which I alter the length of here, for illustration). The variable avgmod.95 returns:

```
> avgmod.95p[[1]][3]
$avg.model
              Estimate  Std. Error Adjusted SE   Lower CI   Upper CI
(Intercept) 56.1637849 15.06079485 15.15303057 26.4643908 85.8631791
X1           1.4810616  0.14016773  0.16302190  1.1615446  1.8005787
X2           0.6850913  0.05397343  0.06358329  0.5604704  0.8097123
X4          -0.6063184  0.05919637  0.06964775 -0.7428255 -0.4698113
X3           0.2126228  0.19480789  0.23502854 -0.2480246  0.6732703
```

which includes the estimated parameter and the lower and upper confidence intervals.

How do I combine all of the outputs from the iteration loop into one data.frame, for example:

```
Variable   Estimate     Lower CI   Upper CI
   X1       1.4810616    1.1615446  1.8005787
   X1
   X1
   X2
```

i.e. I would have three values for X1, X2 and X3 where three is the number of iterations in the loop.

How can this be done? I have tried:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, avgmod.95p)
```

but it doesn't work, in the sense that it provides an error.

Comment: Is the code correct? I get ` 'global.models 'na.action' argument is not set and options('na.action') is "na.omit"` as error.

Comment: I forgot to include the package, should work now.

Comment: Still not working. Can you check the lines `dd<- dredge..` and following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning it to a list, so let's use `lapply`

```
#get number of rows for each model
no.of.rows <-unlist(lapply(avgmod.95p, function(x) nrow(x$avg.model))) 
#use lapply again to rbind the models
foo<-do.call(rbind, lapply(avgmod.95p, function(x) x$avg.model))
```

Now make it into a nice data.frame using no.of rows to indicate which model it came from:

```
result.df <- data.frame(Model.No = rep(seq(1:length(no.of.rows)),no.of.rows),
                        Coefs = rownames(foo),
                        foo)
```

If you modify your index in the for loop, you can give it fancy names as well, and use that.
your avgmod.95p will be named this and we can use that.